# How to handle GROUPBY key(long) values using an aggregate method in kafka API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am facing a problem while adding `KGroupedStream`'s key values of type `(Long,Integer)` to an aggregate method. I mean to say that aggregate doesn't allow a key like the `(Integer, Long, Double)` data type, but it's working fine with the `String` data type `KGroupedStream<String, JsonNode>` using `kstreams` in kafka.

Finally conclude that the aggregate method doesn't allow the key to be like `(Integer, Long)`.

My code so far is:

```
::->groupValue=groupBy((key, value) -> value.asLong(), Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), jsonSerde)); 

groupValue.aggregate(
  new Initializer<Long>() 
  { 
    @Override 
    public Long apply() { return value; } 
  }, 
  new Aggregator<Long, JsonNode, Long>() 
  { 
    public Long apply(Long, JsonNode, Long) 
    { 
      return value1; 
    }
);
```

So please provide a solution to the given problem.

Comment: Any type for key and/or value should work for an aggregation. What problem to you face? Does it not compile? Check out the examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Also, please update your question, instead of adding comments. It's impossible to read in the comment.

Comment: (From Review:) I tried to improve the comprehensibility of your question and also the formatting of the code (incorporated from the comment section) and text.

Comment: Still unclear what the issue is. Does it not compile? What's the error message? I am also not sure what input/output type you want to get? If you say, "aggregate does not allow `(Integer,Long)`", so you mean input or output?

Comment: yeah i wil give straight forward question without groupby function is it possible to do aggregation in kstreams...?